# Remove table row if first cell of that row contains value greater than 50 and lessthan 100 using jquery?

Tags: jquery

Sample table:

```
        <table>
           <tr>
               <td>14</td>
               <td>information</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>70</td>
               <td>information</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>19</td>
               <td>information</td>
           </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("tr td:first-child").each(function() {
    var value = parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
    if(value > 50 && value < 100) {
        $(this).parent().remove();   
    }
});
```

This iterates over the first child (which should always be a `td`) of each `tr` element, gets the text of that child, parses it into a Number, and removes the parent `tr` if necessary.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/Tpm9S/).

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function()
{

    $("tr").each(function()
    {

        if(parseFloat($(this).find("td:first").text()) > 50 &&parseFloat($(this).find("td:first").text()) < 100)
        {

            $(this).remove();

        }

    });

});
```

Not tested! http://jsfiddle.net/ahallicks/BZdTP/ or http://jsfiddle.net/ahallicks/BZdTP/1/

Answer (score 2):

Working: http://jsfiddle.net/XX3fV/1/

```
$.each($('table tr'), function() {
    var f = parseInt($(this).first('td').text());
    if (f > 50 && f < 100)
        $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/Vwzya/

```
$('table tr').each(function () {
    if ( $(this).find('td:first').html() > 50 && $(this).find('td:first').html() < 100 )
        $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Give "mytable" id to table

```
 $('#mytable tr').each(function() {
   var var = $(this).find("td").eq(0).html();
   if(parseInt(var) > 50 && parseInt(var) < 100)
   {
      $(this).remove();
   }        
 }
```